# Flickr-like responsive photo gallery for Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8, theming

Is there a good Drupal 8 module to display a responsive photo gallery, a la Flickr (example: https://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/red)?

I tried [Views Photo Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_photo_grid) but it's not working for me, when I go to create a view type of "Photo grid" per the instructions that option is not listed.

If there's no Drupal 8 module, what'd be the easiest way to go about creating this feature? Creating a photo content type, then a view? Is there a way to pull in the viewport size then dynamically size the thumbnails accordingly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 has built-in Picture module with support of responsive images.
So you need to create new content type "Photo" with image field.
Add some photos of new content type.
Create new view of type "Grid List" and add Photo image field to display.
Or create new view of type "Unformatted", add Photo image field to display, then remove default field formatting, modify CSS.