# Image gallery where I can insert images and video

Tags: 8, media

I'm new to Drupal and is looking for at image gallery, where I can insert images and video, does such exist?

I have tried to search around, but unfortunately without any luck.

Comment: All you need is something that holds media (beginning with 8.4, Media is in core). A way to catalog that media (either by adding to nodes via field, or taxonomy tagging media, etc), then Views to expose it. Page the results, you've got a gallery.

Comment: I thought Media Entity was out of 8.4 @Kevin? It's not in the beta at least

Comment: Oh hm, last I read it had been committed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a ton of ways ...

You can create your own view, see [Flickr-like responsive photo gallery for Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193477/flickr-like-responsive-photo-gallery-for-drupal-8)

Or go for a module like [juicebox](https://www.drupal.org/project/juicebox), or a simple [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) or (my favorite) [photoswipe](https://www.drupal.org/project/photoswipe) gallery. These modules use an image field (with multiple values), and then offer a display for the field. For videos you need to make a view using their handlers, not sure which suppports what now ..

You can go further and further .. fe. by using the [media_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) (now in core ! media 2.0) with [slick_media](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick_media) (more like a slideshow) etc. - see here https://drupal-media.gitbooks.io/drupal8-guide/content/

It really depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to go the view-way :) I'm pretty new to Drupal, so thanks for your help.

Comment: cool - would you mind to accept (and or upvote) the answer then pls